# Format decimal as a percent with specific decimal places

Tags: c#, .net, decimal

```
<%= Model.STPData.InitialRateSetting.HasValue ? Model.STPData.InitialRateSetting.Value.ToString() : "" %>
```

The `Model.STPData.InitialRateSetting` is a decimal. I want to format that as a percentage, and then round it to 5 decimal places. How would I do that?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

you can use

```
Model.STPData.InitialRateSetting.Value.ToString("P5");
```

assuming InitialRateSetting is a decimal

Answer (score 4):

You could use `ToString("p5")`. This will take the number `0.051234567` and display it as "5.12346%". I'm not sure if it'll round that last place, to make sure the behavior or lack thereof is what you want.